# How can I download plain .txt files in Safari/Chrome?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, text

Some data formats will not be automatically downloaded by Safari/Chrome. Usually there are other options:

- `.jpg` → right-click will show a dialog with an option download
- `.pdf` → when you hover over the PDF an option to download appears

How can I download a plain `.txt` file? ([example URL](http://nomediakings.org/everyoneinsilico.txt))

Comment: My Safari has Download Linked File as an option on the right click menu for that example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Safari

1. Highlight URL in the address bar
2. Press <kbd>⌥</kbd> and then <kbd>↩</kbd> to download.

### Chrome

1. *File* -> *Save As*

   - No options appear as to what the downloaded format is. For a plain `.txt` file it will be a simple text file.

Comment: Chrome: Alt+Click on Link

Comment: @MaxRied Oh yeah! Thanks. However, this does not work with the URL in the address bar. That's why I've never tried it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't post it as an answer, but I think it's also interesting for your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a page with a link to a txt/plain text, do a **right-click** on the link and choose "Download Linked File" or "Download Linked File As ...".
Per default the file will go in your Downloads folder.

If you're already on the txt page/plain texte page, do a <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> .(to select all the text) then a <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (to copy) the text, then you can paste it where you want (<kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

If you already with the URL in the address bar, just open it, and right click on the page and an option `save as...` should appear.

Answer (score -2):

1. Find the text to copy (or in this case, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
2. Copy the whole text (= <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
3. Open TextEdit and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the text.
4. Vwoila!

Comment: Are you sure you read the question?

Comment: I think an experienced Mac user like gentmatt would have thought on this... I think he's looking for something more profound and performant!

Answer (score -2):

If you use PHP then it might be easy one for you using "Content-disposition:" tag. It forces the browser to download the given file, without displaying or playing it.

Make a small php script and upload your file in the same folder. The sample script is

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=movie.mpg');
header('Content-type: video/mpeg');
readfile('movie.mpg');
?>
```

Found this solution at http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html